# Ignore specific pacage dependcy on pip

Tags: python, pip

How can I enforce the pip install command to ignore the installation of pacake_which_conflict_with_flask, considering the requirements in App1 and App2? I want to achieve this without making any changes to App2. Here's the current state of the requirements files:

App1/requirements.txt:

```
flask==2.3.2
App2
```

App2/requirements.txt:

```
pymssql
pymongo
pacake_which_conflict_with_flask_2.3.2
```

Is there a way to modify App1/requirements.txt in order to instruct pip to ignore the installation of pacake_which_conflict_with_flask? My desired outcome is to run the following command without installing pacake_which_conflict_with_flask:

```
python -m pip install -r App1/requirements.txt
```

another solution is to modify the pip install command to instruct pip to ignore the installation of pacake_which_conflict_with_flask.